# Jenkins/Hudson Master server?

Tags: jenkins

Currently I have Jenkins/Hudson master in VM with 8G ram and 250 GB space and connected different slaves which are Physical box and is this okay? More over no jobs build jobs are running Or Master should be a physical box? Any performance improve I would gain? Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the master is not building components itself (`# of executors` in Node-Configuration) it does not do anything else then providing the Webinterface to Jenkins. I don't think that there is a big difference in comparison to a physical webserver.

Usually using a VM as a build-system is slower than directly using physical hardware. But this depends on the software you're using for running the VM.

Comment: No, I know as actual build server is physical machine, but I got VM for Hudson master as did not have enough resources then.So I think I am good to go to connect number of machines I want as a slave.

Comment: VM is okay as far as no jobs are running